# How do I make a separator between two TextViews but keep them synchronized for line wrapping?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

## This is what I want

[image: This is what I want essentially]

So basically a layout, that has two `TextView`, they must be separated with a vertical line, and most importantly, it should maintain line wrapping, so in the third line, the message is too long and wrapped, and thus the nickname on the left keeps one empty line for it

## What did I try

I tried to add two `TextView`, and a `View` between them:
First `TextView` is called `nicks` and the other is called `messages`

**nicks:** `match_parent` height, `wrap_content` width

**View1:** `match_parent` height, `1dp` width, `@color/darker_grey` background

**messages:** `match_parent` height, `0dp` width, `1` weight

**Programmatically:** Whenever pushing a message `nicks.append("\n" + theNickToPush);` and `messages.append("\n" + theMessageToPush);`

However, when line wrapping occurs in the `messages`, `nicks` doesn't reflect that and keep one empty line for it, that ends up with having an extra offset between the nickname and its messages whenever line wrapping occurs.

## What I might as well like to do later

[image: My extra approach]
As you can see, there's even one more separator, for a timestamp

Comment: It sounds like you might want a TableLayout instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. The nick should have `layout_gravity="top"`. Seomthing like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:width="match_parent"
  android:height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <!-- The nick -->
  <TextView
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"/>

  <View
    android:width="1dp"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:background:"@color/dark_gray"/>

  <!-- The message-->
  <TextView
    android:width="0dp"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This would be quite easy to extend to include timestamps as well if you want to.

Comment: Isn't that exactly as what I did? Maybe you meant to make an instance of this layout for each message? Well, isn't that too much for a single line? Because I'll be having tons of messages

Comment: I meant making an instance of this layout for each message, yes. If you are showing these on a recycler view, you'd be using the ViewHolder pattern, so you should be fine (it's not such a complex layout after all).

Comment: How do you manage the messages's nick/message separator to line up? I mean nicks don't have the same length